# Environment var _

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I send a printenv command in the commandline and I see one of the variables is the following:

```
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

I now do this:

```
mo@mo-Toshiba ~/Workspace $ printenv _
/usr/bin/printenv
```

but when trying to call echo on this variable I get the following:

```
mo@mo-Toshiba ~/Workspace $ echo $_
_
```

What gives? Why doesn't echo treat this as a variable? (ie. like $PATH or $PWD)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a variable. The [shell variable `_`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005f) is updated by the shell each time you run a command to contain the last argument of the previous command.

It isn't useful very often, but it lets you write an alias or function to perform something on “the same file (or other object) as the last command”.

The variable is also added to the environment of subprocesses. There, it contains the name of the command as passed in the shell (before `PATH` lookup).